# How can I group ORM results into unread, recent and older in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, resultset

I am trying to group my results in three categories: unread, recent, and older; like so:

```
array(
'unread' => ...,
'recent' => ...,
'older' => '''
);
```

But I am having difficulties achieving that.

Here's what I've done, I don't know where I missed it. It's giving me an empty result.

```
/**
 * Categorize results into three groups of unread, recent and older
 *
 * @param Query|null $query
 * @return Query
 */
public function categorize(Query $query = null)
{
    if (!$query) {
        $query = $this->find();
    }
    $query = $query->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
            return $exp->addCase(
                [
                    //  Unread notifications
                    $q->newExpr()->eq('Notifications.is_read', 0),

                    // Created between now and 4 days back, that has been read
                    $q->newExpr()->between(
                        'Notifications.created',
                        new \DateTime('now'),
                        new \DateTime('-4 days')
                    ),

                    // Older than 4 days back
                    $q->newExpr()->lt('Notifications.created', new \DateTime('-4 days'))
                ],
                ['unread',  'recent', 'older'],
                ['string', 'string', 'string']
            );
        });

    return $query;
}
```

Please, what am I missing? Thanks in advance...

Here's the expected and generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    Notifications.id AS `Notifications__id`,
    Notifications.refid AS `Notifications__refid`,
    Notifications.type AS `Notifications__type`,
    Notifications.user_refid AS `Notifications__user_refid`,
    Notifications.initiator_refid AS `Notifications__initiator_refid`,
    Notifications.subject_source AS `Notifications__subject_source`,
    Notifications.subject_refid AS `Notifications__subject_refid`,
    Notifications.subject_permalink AS `Notifications__subject_permalink`,
    Notifications.message AS `Notifications__message`,
    Notifications.is_read AS `Notifications__is_read`,
    Notifications.created AS `Notifications__created`,
    Notifications.modified AS `Notifications__modified` 
FROM
    notifications Notifications 
WHERE
    (
        user_refid = :c0 
        AND 
        CASE
            WHEN
                Notifications.is_read = :c1 
            THEN
                :param2 
            WHEN
                Notifications.created BETWEEN :c3 AND :c4 
            THEN
                :param5 
            WHEN
                Notifications.created < :c6 
            THEN
                :param7 
        END
    )
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect that query object to do? What SQL do you expect it to generate? Have you checked the generated SQL (for example with DebugKit)?

Comment: @ndm Thanks for your response. And yes, I have. I am updating the question to include the expected and generated SQL, but it isn't yeilding result:

Comment: The expected SQL matches what is generated? If not, we need to see both. And what does "it isn't yielding result" mean? You get no results? Wrong records? Right records but not arranged how you want?

Comment: Certainly that can't be the expected SQL. I'm poking at this because it doesn't make sense, that `CASE` clause will always return a string, which would always evaluate to  `true`, so it doesn't have any effect, and even if it would would conditionally evaluate to `false`, ie have an actual effect, it still wouldn't help with grouping anything! This should probably be in `SELECT` clause. What I'm trying to get to is whether you actually know what the SQL needs to look like, whether your problem is to create the query? Maybe what you're showing is just an attempt at solving a different problem?